# discord.py on_message_delete get message content

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm attempting to make a log of when a user's message is deleted, but I'm unable to see the actual message's contents when sending it to a channel:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    embed1 = discord.Embed(title="Deleted Message!")
    embed1.add_field(name=f"**Msg Was Deleted**", value=f"Someone Has Deleted The Following:\n`{message}`", inline=True)
    embed1.colour = (0x90EE90)
    dele = bot.get_channel(722832289955971183)
    await dele.send(embed=embed1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The "junk" it's spitting out is the message object. This object has many attributes you can access - see the `discord.Message` object in the references.

To get the message's contents, you can use the `content` attribute of a message like so:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    # Code
    embed.add_field(name="..", value=f"Someone has deleted the following:\n{message.content}")
    # Rest of the code
```

---

**References:**

- [`on_message_delete()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message_delete)
- [`discord.Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message)
- [`Message.content`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.content)